# how do I convert date format using bteq script?

Tags: database, type-conversion, teradata

I'm loading data from  a flat file which the date data are in 20150605 format....However, I need to convert it into yyy-mm-dd before loading it into Teradata. I tried the following, but it unfortunately failed.

```
Values
( Format(:a, 'YYYY-MM-DD')

);
```

How do I convert this type of data conversion. For others, it would be

```
(:a (integer))
```

if I've not mistaken...

Answer (score 0):

The FORMAT clause describes the external data. Using this Teradata-specific cast syntax:

```
(:a (DATE, FORMAT 'yyyymmdd'))
```

For something other than FastLoad / TPT LOAD, you could also use

```
CAST(:a AS DATE FORMAT'yyyymmdd')
```